# UICollectionViewCell disappears after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell subclass. The cell has two sizes which I'm setting in sizeForItemAtIndexPath method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 60);
    if ([[[_locationsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hasAlert"] boolValue]) {
        size = CGSizeMake(320, 155);
    }
    return size;
}
```

When all items have the same size, everything is okay. The problem occurs when there are cells of various sizes and I delete one of them and then after reloadData all cells disappear. The method for deleting cells is following:

```
-(void)MyCollectionViewCell:(MyCollectionViewCell *)cell didDeleteRowForIndex:(int)index{
    [_locationTable performBatchUpdates:^(void){
        [_locationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        [_locationTable deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self updatePlist];
        [_locationTable reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? BTW It works when I'm not reloading the collectionView but then the indexPaths don't match the cells.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other related code?  I set up a small example with the methods you provided (which deletes on selection), and I wasn't able to reproduce the bug.  Here is the example I used to try to reproduce the error: http://pastebin.com/arCyjgCU

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried to trace when this issue is occurring. It is very inconsistent. Sometimes it happens when I delete cell sometimes when I add one and sometimes when the size of some cells is updated. I think that there must be a better way to do this. Maybe subclassing a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and just resize the cells there rather than reloading the UICollectionView every time something changes?